# round off the amount if checkbox is checked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

if the checkbox is checked the total amount should be roundoff. if the checkbox is unchecked the total value in decimals in angular js
tell me from starting, I didn't start
$scope.checked=?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly. I get that you want to round a number if a checkbox is checked, but where are things not working? You need to post the code you've tried so we can help